# "No matching client found for package name ..." since I added firebase in my project

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

When I tried to launch my code on a virtual device, I've got this error:

> Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode... Running
> Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Invalid depfile:
> C:\Users\mchev\AndroidStudioProjects\fll_score_brainstormers.dart_tool\flutter_build\3ed18d41ff56fda06725619fd750edaa\kernel_snapshot.d Invalid depfile:
> C:\Users\mchev\AndroidStudioProjects\fll_score_brainstormers.dart_tool\flutter_build\3ed18d41ff56fda06725619fd750edaa\kernel_snapshot.d

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> No matching client found for package name 'com.PhilippesGames.fll_score_brainstormers'

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8m 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
can you please help me ?